# Does refraction or diffraction cause rainbows?

Tags: optics, visible-light

The title is explicit. I just read several web pages about rainbows and all of them refers both to refraction and diffraction. Things are not really clear in my mind, and to fix this, I'd like to have a unambiguous idea of the phenomenon :

Is diffraction or refraction at the origin of rainbows or both of them ?

Comment: @ Benoit the accepted answer is completely incorrect. Please reconsider your choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diffraction, interference, refraction, reflection, diffuse reflection, specular reflection, transmission, dispersion, separation of colors, *internal* reflection, *total* internal reflection, spectrum, rainbow, etc. Frequently these words and phrases get tossed around carelessly, and sometimes interchangeably. Sometimes this is completely wrong, and other times it is just incomplete and misleading. But it happens several ways in a naive explanation of rainbows that, while completely incorrect, nevertheless gets taught in schools. Being more careful with the words eliminates these problems.

*Diffraction* refers to specific kind of *interference* of light waves. It has nothing to do with true rainbows, but some rainbow-like effects ([glories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glory_(optical_phenomenon))) are caused by diffraction.

*Reflection* and *Transmission* refer to what happens when light traveling in one medium encounters a boundary with another. Reflection means it bounces off the boundary, and stays in the first medium. There are two kinds: *specular*, which reflects in a single direction described by the Law of Reflection; and *diffuse*, which reflects in many directions.

*Transmission* means the light enters the second medium. It changes direction according to Snell's Law. This change is called *refraction*, although sometimes that word is incorrectly used to mean transmission. The refraction is different for each color of light. This results in *dispersion*, which means only that even though you could ignore color in the first medium, you can't in the second. Under controlled circumstances, like sunlight passed through a pinhole or a slit, dispersion causes *separation of colors*. A prism can separate a pinhole or slit of light into the individual colors, called a *spectrum*. But shine the full sun on that prism, and you get a smear of mostly white light. Dispersion is still happening, but is separation?

At large angles, transmission can't occur when light tries to leave a denser material like water and enter a sparser one like air, because Snell's Law has no solution. So all the light reflects. This is called *Total Internal Reflection*, or TIR. It's what makes diamonds sparkle, and fiber-optic cables work. But it's also what makes air bubbles in water appear shiny when it happens on the **outside** of the bubble. So "internal" does not refer to inside an object, it only refers to inside the first medium. Since that is what "reflection" means, it is redundant.

Rainbows are caused by light that enters a raindrop, reflects one or more times internally (not TIR), and exits. It refracts both times it crosses the boundary. When you consider all of the light hitting the drop - something most explanations do not do - you will see that the light will be spread out into a cone of light that depends on the color and number of internal reflections. If the number is odd, the center of this cone will be straight back towards the sun; if even, it will be in the same direction as the original light.

Two effects related to this cone cause rainbows. (1) The outer edge of the cone is much brighter than its interior and appears as a bright band; and (2) The width of the cone is different for each color due to dispersion. Red's cone is widest, and its band is seen on the outside (see note below) of the rainbow, where no other colors are seen. Violet's cone is narrowest, and it is mixed with all the other colors. We see it as violet because it is brighter; but is a paler violet than you would see in a spectrum.

Note: The cones making the secondary rainbow are about 125° to 130° wide. They wrap around the top of the sky, and the bright bands are seen on the opposite side of the center of the cone with the colors upside down.

Answer (score 0):

The rainbows seen in the sky are caused by rain droplets which are double-refracting the light from the sun.  As the wavelengths increase, from red towards blue, the index of refraction increases so that the colors are dispersed in the colors of the rainbow.

Imagine the sun is behind you, with the rain drops in front of you - then the rainbow is the visible portion of a circle centered about the line from the sun through your head.

Airplane pilots often see the complete circle of the rainbow.

See, for example, http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refrn/Lesson-4/Rainbow-Formation

Diffraction results in dispersion of colors in the direction opposite to that of the primary rainbow. You see that when you look at the surface of a CD/DVD or other finely ruled surface.  It is not involved in the development of ordinary rainbows caused by the sun and the rain.

Comment: Without the dispersion properties of water (NOT diffraction), there would be no rainbow, even with the double-refracting.

Comment: @BillN: dispersion is just the result of the dependence of the index of refraction on the wavelength of light; it is not an independent property of light.  When demonstrating the experimental dispersion of light, e.g., with a prism, I would then explain how it originates via material properties as the index of refraction changes.  But I would only do this if we were going to go on to a discussion of Snell's law or the eikonal equation.

Comment: Diffraction involves having barriers/edges that result in interference effects. That doesn't happen in weather rainbows. The colors you see in a rainbow are the result of the dispersion properties of the water, combined with the refraction and reflection. The rainbow in the CD disk is due to diffraction from the pits and plateaus of the disk. Totally different physics for the same visible effect: showing that white light has multiple wavelengths.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow#/media/File:Rainbow1.svg

Comment: My point in the first comment is that if water did not refract different wavelengths different amount, there wouldn't be a rainbow. So, refraction plus dispersion property of water is needed for rainbows. It's not refraction alone.

Comment: I don't know why you say that.

Answer (score -2):

Both of them.  Diffraction refers to how electric fields propagate through free space and through media with an index of refraction.  Refraction refers to how light rays "bend" at an interface between to media with different indices of refraction.

The rainbow is created because the index of refraction of water droplets changes as a function of wavelength.  So, when the light enters the water droplet different colors will bend at different angles thus producing a dispersive effect known as a rainbow.

Comment: Are you confusing diffraction with dispersion?

Comment: The rainbow phenomena as you describe it is completely attributable to refraction and not at all to diffraction.